# Kotlin, Retrofit, ClassCastException, com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to List<CatListItem>?

Tags: kotlin, casting, gson, retrofit, classcastexception

My interface

```
interface ApiService {
    @GET("URL")
    fun getCatList(
        @Query("var1") var1: String,
        @Query("var2") var2: String,
    ): Call<List<CatListItem>?>
}
```

My Helper

```
class ApiClient {
    companion object {
        private lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit

        fun getClient(): Retrofit {
            val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()

            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiConstants.baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build()

            return retrofit
        }
    }
}
```

My Api

```
    override fun getCatList(var1: String, var2: String) {
        val apiInterface: ApiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService::class.java)

        val call = apiInterface.getCatList(var1, var2)

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<CatListItem>?> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<CatListItem>?>, response: Response<List<CatListItem>?>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val answer = CatList(response.body())
                    return
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<CatListItem>?>, t: Throwable) {
                call.cancel()
            }
        })
    }
```

My data class

```
data class CatList(

    @field:SerializedName("catList")
    val catList: List<CatListItem?>? = null
)

data class CatListItem(

    @field:SerializedName("name")
    val name: String? = null,
)
```

My JSON

```
[{"name":"1"},{"name":"2"}]
```

My ProGuard rules

```
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking interface retrofit2.Call
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.*
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation

-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.reflect.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.internal.** { *; }

-keep class * implements java.io.Serializable { *; }

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    *;
}
```

Logcat in Release Mode, all ok in Debug Mode except for Release Mode

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to q2.a
                                                                                                        at o2.c.run(Unknown Source:385)
                                                                                                        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:562)
                                                                                                        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)
```

The problem is in APK Release mode, in Debug mode all is ok.

I changed the Timeouts, and nothing changed. Also tested a runBlocking with suspend fun in interface, nothing changed. Looks like something is missing. I suppect that this happenned internally processing the List?

Need your help to solve this. Thanks in advance for support.

Comment: also, keep your `data class`

Comment: Yes I have this rule in Proguard Tools. Where entities, are all my data class -keep class com.project.project_name.domain.entities.* { *; }

Comment: Could you please try `-keepattributes Signature`, it is [mentioned in the R8 FAQ](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/master/compatibility-faq.md#kotlin-suspend-functions-and-generic-signatures) (though in the context of suspend functions, but maybe it applies in general)

Comment: @JulioLeon I am facing this exact issue and the solution you mentioned below does not work for me. Let me know if you had any other insights.

Comment: @NameisNilay have you found solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for your answer.

The solution for my problem was:
-Comment my fun getCatList(var1: String, var2: String).
-Compile release.
-Then Uncomment my function.
-And compile again.

No idea why this is the solution for this problem.

But worked for me.

If someone can tell me why this, will help me to understand if something is missed in this project.

Later.